# How to measure the CURRENT voltage and current from the battery of an android phone?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am working on a NEXUS S phone
 I wanted to read the current supplied by battery, I suppose that this can be done reading a system updated file on the phone.
I read somewhere that it can be done by reading a file at

/sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_current

but there is no such file in this phone called batt_current or current_now......
(On other phones there is one!!)
Though I could see a file named voltage_now which showed me the current value of voltage supplied by the battery

Does anyone know where can I find the CURRENT current supplied by the battery....

Answer (score 4):

Unlike many devices, the Samsung devices do not expose the current value. It's a Hardware issue and Nexus S is based on a Samsung Hardware.

Check the note of [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manor.currentwidget&hl=en) application description *The electric current reading doesn't work on all devices. The reason is that the manufactures (mostly Motorola and Samsung) don't support this in the battery driver or in the hardware.*